# App gets hanged while trying to read contacts

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I'm working on an app which reads the phone contacts and displays them in the form of list. I have to send message to selected contacts from the list. But the problem is that the app gets hanged if the mobile has more than 500 contacts. I don't get where the problem is..

I found this code on internet and implemented in my app. Contacts will be displayed but after taking so much time. Here is my code

```
ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null,null,null);
if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
   while (cur.moveToNext()) {
      String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
      String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
      if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(
         ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
         Cursor pCur = 
                cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                null, 
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +"=?", 
                new String[]{id}, null);
         while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
              int phoneType = pCur.getInt(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
              String phoneNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(
                  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
              switch (phoneType) {
                    case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                        Log.e(name + "(mobile number)", phoneNumber);
                        break;
                    case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                        Log.e(name + "(home number)", phoneNumber);
                        break;
                    case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                        Log.e(name + "(work number)", phoneNumber);
                        break;
                    case Phone.TYPE_OTHER:
                        Log.e(name + "(other number)", phoneNumber);
                        break;                                  
                    default:
                        break;
              }
          } 
          pCur.close();
    }
} }
```

Comment: And what is your problem? Lags, contacts not showing? Please give us more information

Comment: post your code as well

Answer (score 2):

To read contacts -

```
private void fetchContacts() {
    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        if (name == null || name.equals(""))
            name = phoneNumber;
        if (Utils.notNull(phoneNumber)) {
            phoneNumber = Utils.checkAndWrapMobileNumber(getApplicationContext(), phoneNumber);
            allContacts.put(phoneNumber, name);
            contactList.add(phoneNumber);
        }
    }
    phones.close();
}
```

And better to use this code in AssyncTask so read in background thread.

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

it is due to heavy task in `UI` thread that blocks `UI`, Use `AyncTask` for this purpose.